# Как написанный код взаимодействует с посторонней программой?

Tags: python, ооп, многопоточность, файлы, функции

Я честно не знаю как задать этот вопрос, так как изучаю программирование совсем недавно. Но вопрос следующий. Код написанный мной можем взаимодействовать с другими программами разными способами: либо через имитацию движений мыши, либо через системное взаимодействие. Попытаюсь объяснить на примере: на питоне можно написать скрипт который будет имитировать движение мыши(открытие браузера, ввод нужного поискового запроса и тд..)для отправки email, а есть специальные библиотеки, которые способны отправить нужное письмо не открывая браузер и почту. Мне крайне интересно как самому написать функцию, которая будет взаимодействовать с почтой на системном уровне и как вообще это устроено. Буду благодарен если проясните этот вопрос на примерах, либо оставив ссылку на нужную литературу

Заранее прошу прощение за форму вопроса, знаю о программировании очень мало, поэтому и не могу задать адекватно вопрос

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если просто нужно получать и отправлять почту, то для этого существуют протоколы IMAP и SMTP
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP

Answer (score 0):

Способов взаимодействия программ друг с другом достаточно много.

Сначала нужно понять какой тип взаимодействия нужен: синхронный или асинхронный.

В зависимости от выбора нужно подбирать тип взаимодействия.
Если коротко, то основные типы такие:

1. Отсылка сообщений
2. COM объекты
3. Использование сборок DLL
4. Использование протоколов

Каждый из этих типов взаимодействия разветвляется на много подвидов.
Думаю, этот список можно дополнить.